# how to make uitableview can not to be pulled when scrolled at the top

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

By default, the uitableview still can be pulled when scrolled at the top if it,
I want to make the uitableview can not to be pulled when it's first cell scroll to the top of it.(Like AppStore)

code `tableView.bounces = NO;` make scrolling not smooth, so it is not what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the alwaysBounceVertical property:

```
tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;
```

From [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIScrollView), "A Boolean value that determines whether bouncing always occurs when vertical scrolling reaches the end of the content."

If you're using a xib or storyboard you can also uncheck the "Bounce Vertically" property of the scroll view in the Attributes Inspector:

[image: Bounce Vertically]

Comment: where do you set the property?

Comment: `_tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWiithFrame:....];    
    _tableView.delegate = self;
    _tableView.dataSource = self;
    _tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:_tableView];`

Comment: Sorry about rejecting your edit - sometimes it isn't immediately obvious what it does.  It's usually better to be specific in suggested edit summary about what it does - I've approved your second edit.

Comment: also set _tableView.bounces = NO; (:

Answer (score 1):

Use only,

tableView.bounces = NO;

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in the storyboard under the attribute inspector, disable bounces vertical.  It will make your code a lot cleaner compared to setting a property programmatically.